# If $g:V \rightarrow V$ is an injective linear transformation. Prove if $V$ is finite dimensional then $g$ is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> I am asked to prove this without the rank nullity theorem

**My Attempt at a Proof**

For the $\implies$;
If $g:V \rightarrow V$  is injective then the dimension of the kernel is 0, and so as ($im$) and ($ker$) are both subspaces of $V$, $dim(im)=dim(v)$ which implies $g$ is surjective.

For the $\impliedby$ ;
If $g:V \rightarrow V$  is surjective, then $dim(v)=dim(im)$ and $dim(ker)$ must be 0, so $g$ is injective.

It seems to me that i have indirectly used the  rank nullity theorem, would there be a more suitable proof that doesn't incorporate it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your argument in $\implies$. It appears to me that you're using the rank nullity theorem in $\Longleftarrow$. And from your title I think it sounds that you're only aske to prove $\implies$.

Comment: Oop! I forgot the "dim" before "ker", any linear transformation is injective if and only if the dimension of a kernel is 0, is it not?

Comment: Yes. That's the part I understand. Everything after "and so as..." is what I cannot follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis for $V$ (so $V$ has dimension $n$), then since $g$ is injective, $g(v_1),\ldots,g(v_n)$ is linearly independent. However, it's a linearly independent set of $n$ vectors, and $V$ has dimension $n$, so it's a basis, hence the image of $g$ contains the span of $g(v_1),\ldots,g(v_n)$, which being a basis, is all of $V$.

Comment: hmm... is $g(v_1),...,g(v_n)$ necessarily independent and not just unique?

Comment: I assume by "unique" you mean "distinct". Anyway, yes, they must be independent. Suppose they satisfy a linear depedence relation $a_1g(v_1) + \cdots + a_ng(v_n) = 0$. But this means $g(a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n) = 0$. Since $g$ is injective, this means $a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n = 0$, but since the $v_i$ are linearly independent, implies that the $a_i$'s are all 0.

Comment: @otupygak hey, if you don't mind please accept this answer if it satisfactorily answered your question.